# What is wrong with my server?

Tags: java, network-programming

I'm facing small difficulties with my Java server, basically it works, but only for one line, when I'm adding another it doesn't send it, here is the snippet for server:

```
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
if (toSend.length() != 0) {
    out.print(toSend);
    out.flush();
    System.out.println("connected");
    toSend.setLength(0);
    changeStatusTS(NULL, true);
}
if (in.ready()) {
    s = in.readLine();
    if ((s != null) && (s.length() != 0)) {
        appendToChatBox("INCOMING: " + s + "\n");
        if (s.equals("51789181 19426953") == true) {

            out.println(ms.lister().toString().replace('[', ' ').replace(']', ' ').trim().replace(',', ' ') + "" + '\n');
            out.println(ms.topicDesc().toString().replace('[', ' ').replace(']', ' ').trim().replace(',', ' ') + "" + '\n');
            out.flush();

        }
    }
}
```

and the receiving part:

```
clientSocket = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 1234);
DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
sentenceX = "" + point.getLatitudeE6();
sentenceY = "" + point.getLongitudeE6();
outToServer.writeBytes(sentenceX + " " + sentenceY + '\n');

String interesting = inFromServer.readLine();
String[] holder = interesting.split("\\s+");

String title = inFromServer.readLine();
String[] titleHolder = title.split("\\s+");
```

dalvik monitor is printing the error as:

```
TCP Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

The program is working, but it doesn't receive the second `out.println();`

Comment: Look carefully at the line where the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` happens (the stack trace tells you in which line of code of which source file it happens). You're accessing an array there with an invalid index. Find out why the index is invalid. Add some log statements to find out exactly what it's doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a guess: the second `inFromServer.readLine()` call could be too fast. The second packet might not be sent/received at this time... maybe checking if the string is `ready()` might be a good idea